# How to pass data between screens in flutter using BLoC?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, bloc, stream-builder

Here is my situation: I have a sign up in my app. I am doing this in five screens, also using BLoC and StreamBuilder in the TextFormFields. When all the data are filled I send all of this to my API via BloC.

The problem is: when I pass to the second screen all the data from the first screen are lost, causing then an error.

How do I solve this, in order words, how do I keep the data while I am navigating between the screens?

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach
create a file called

**global_variables.dart**

and in it for example

```
String value="value";
```

and in the pages you want to use

```
import 'global_variables.dart';
```

and you can use value easily or even set it with another value